# Rails: validates uniqueness through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

I have the following Models:

```
Language

Itemtype

Item
    belongs_to :itemtype

LocalisedItem
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :language
```

The LocalisedItem model has an attribute called "title".

I want to validate the uniqueness of said "title" attribute. My problem is the scope: It´s supposed to be unique per language (easy) and itemtype, which I could not figure out how to do until now.

My best try...

```
validates :title, :uniqueness => { :scope => [:language_id, 'item.itemtype_id'] }
```

...fails with "NoMethodError: undefined method `item.itemtype_id'".

Is there any way to check for uniqueness in the way described?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format for validate uniqueness with a scope:

`validates_uniqueness_of :title, :scope => :language_id`